# When closing a tabpage on a Tabcontrol, call form.close

Tags: c#, custom-controls, tabcontrol, visual-studio-2019

Within my application i am trying to use forms in tabpages. These forms are all data managing forms.
I edited the tabcontrol (created a custom tabcontrol) so i can remove tabpages by double clicking on the tabheader.

```
protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
  //* Default method of closing a tab.
  if (Selectedtab != null)
    TabPages.Remove(Selectedtab);
}
```

Although it works. Its actually not doing what I need. 
Because any changes on the form in the tabpage, are lost, regardless of the below

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
  private void SomeForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (HasChanges() && CustomMessage.WarningBox("There is unsaved data. Are you sure you want to close"))
            return;
        ((TabControl)((TabPage)this.Parent).Parent).TabPages.Remove((TabPage)this.Parent);
    }
}
```

When setting a breakpoint at this function, it never enters.

 Now my question: Is it possible to call the Close method of the form from Tabcontrol. Preferably something like below.

```
protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
  if (Selectedtab != null)
  {
    if (Selectedtab.EmbeddedForm != null)
      TabPages.ASelectedtab.EmbeddedForm.Close();
  }
}
```

The main problem I am facing is I don't know how to access a function on a form from only knowing the selected tab. And I cant find it either.

---

Solution after using KyleWangs answer as base:
Custom Control:

```
protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
  string frmSearchName = "Frm" + SelectedTab.Name.Substring(3);
  Form f = (Form)Application.OpenForms[frmSearchName];
  if (f != null)
    f.Close();
  else
    TabPages.Remove(SelectedTab);
}
```

Form:

```
private void SomeForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  SetChanges();
  if (HasChanges() && !CustomMessage.WarningBox("There is unsaved data. Are you sure you want to close?"))
    e.Cancel = true;
  else
    ((TabControl)((TabPage)this.Parent).Parent).TabPages.Remove((TabPage)this.Parent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use property [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netframework-4.8) to get the open form instance.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Clear();
    PageForm1 f1 = new PageForm1();
    AddNewTab(f1);
}

private void AddNewTab(Form frm)
{
    TabPage tab = new TabPage(frm.Text);
    frm.TopLevel = false;
    frm.Parent = tab;
    frm.Visible = true;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
    frm.Location = new Point((tab.Width - frm.Width) / 2, (tab.Height - frm.Height) / 2);
    tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
}

private void tabControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form f = (Form)Application.OpenForms[tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text];
    f.Close();
    tabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement it in my custom tabcontrol, but its not yet making any difference. Is it only possible from the actual Form a tabcontrol is placed at?

Comment: The demo is using the default TabControl

Comment: Thanks, i think i got the idea, and the issue might lie in the fact that the text/name of the selected tab is not the same as the text/name of form. So my implementation method should be so that i can replace a few characters (replace prefix). Ill let you know if what i planned works.

Comment: Thanks. ALthough i had to make a few changes. What I intended works now. I'll mark yours as accepted answer because its what I needed as base.